# calendar with struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, dojo

I currently work with struts2 and I need to display a calendar

in my jsp page and retrieve the date in yyyy-MM-dd

I try with this code

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
     <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<sx:head cache="false" compressed="false" /> 

</head>
<body>


<sx:datetimepicker name="date achat" label="Format (yyyy-MM-dd)" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>



</body>
</HTML>
```

but while running the schedule does not appear

and just this label is displayed

```
 Format (yyyy-MM-dd):
```

best regards

franco

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example

[Struts2 DateTimePicker](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-datetimepicker-example/)

Comment: the example you provide is not working it does not show the field tag.